# Obtain Music Category with Foursquare API?

Tags: api, foursquare

There's anyway that I can obtain the music category of a band with the Foursquare API? if not there's a chance to obtain it from other way?

Comment: Define "music category of a band"... like, the genre of music they perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories for a list of categories used by foursquare.

The musical genre of a band is not available in foursquare.

Comment: thank you very much I see there's no option on doing so. nevermind

Answer (score 0):

You can get categories of the bands via lastfm api http://www.last.fm/api

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While you can use the Last.FM API the question was specifically about the Foursquare API, to which there's already an answer for.